# Why doensn't my ubuntu 19.04 boot?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have installed Ubuntu 19.04 from a USB stick flashed by startup disk creator. I have got the Ubuntu 19.04 ISO (development version) from the Ubuntu website. The first time after installation it booted without any problem. But I was advised to install updates by the software updater, it downloaded and installed updates and then asked for restart. Once shutdown, it shows a blank black screen for hours together when startup as soon as the BIOS screen disappears. I dual boot Ubuntu 18.04(in 80GB HDD) and 19.04(in another 51GB partition of a 500 GB HDD). I guess this is a problem due to improper flashing of my USB. Help me I am a noob to Ubuntu.Help me.

Update: it happens even to the normal version

Comment: Maybe you did everything right. What's the make and model of your PC? What video adapter does it use? Search for answered 'black screen' questions here; answered questions have a number in white on a green block at the left instead of green on white.

Comment: 19.04 development version??   Ubuntu 19.04 was released 2019-April-18 (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/04/19/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-released/) so a development version means it was a version before the release.  For starters you have a very old alpha/beta/final unreleased TEST version that may have issues that were fixed the next day (development releases are released daily - the date is found in the the /etc/apt/sources.list) - so your ISO is wrong for starters.  19.04 has been released.  *Example of issue; for ~two weeks Lubuntu 19.04 dailies had GNOME on them so logging was GNOME not LXQt*